# data parsed to database Nokogiri rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

So I'm just getting started with Nokogiri and Rails
I have the following which returns the name of someone.

TEST.rb:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1439629/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))  


puts doc.css("div#wrapper [...too long...]")[0].text
```

Now I created a table in my DB on rails and want to send the returned name to the actor table in the name column! How would I do that ? I can't seem to find atutorial on this...

My goal would eventually be to have a rails form where I'd input an IMDB link which would return title and so on...

(Also I'm new to ruby rails and programming so please provide easy info!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at these:

1. http://ericlondon.com/posts/249-a-ruby-class-to-crawl-a-website-using-nokogiri-mongodb-database-and-mongomapper-orm
2. http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/toc/

The second is the best resource by far - It has an entire project on scrapping with Nokogiri.

Answer (score 0):

When using rails you use migrations to create databases and create or modify tables in your database. Here is the official article about that: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

When you create a Model (and a table that belongs to it) you can access the table using the ActiveRecord model like this:

```
object = ModelName.new({has of data})
object.save
```

Or to find them

```
ModelName.find(id_of_object_in_db)
```

You should read the whole section dealing with models:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/